# Error: gas required exceeds allowance or always failing transaction at chrome-extension

Tags: remix, metamask, ropsten

I'm using Remix, Metamask, ROPSTEN and can not deploy any contract...always getting the same message...it used to work...not working any more...happens in different machines, happens with Chrome or Firefox...seems to be related to the estimation routine...

> GAS ESTIMATION FAILED
>
> Gas estimation errored with the following message (see below). The transaction execution will likely fail. Do you want to force sending? 
>   Error: gas required exceeds allowance or always failing transaction at chrome-extension://nkbihfbeogaeaoehlefnkodbefgpgknn/background.js:1:1723632 at chrome-

Let me know if you have a similar setting and it works...or any known issues...

Thank you !

Here's the Code:

```
pragma solidity ^0.4.20;
contract Ballot {

    struct Voter {
        uint weight;
        bool voted;
        uint8 vote;
        address delegate;
    }
    struct Proposal {
        uint voteCount;
    }

    address chairperson;
    mapping(address => Voter) voters;
    Proposal[] proposals;

    /// Create a new ballot with $(_numProposals) different proposals.
    function Ballot(uint8 _numProposals) public {
        chairperson = msg.sender;
        voters[chairperson].weight = 1;
        proposals.length = 3;
    }

    /// Give $(toVoter) the right to vote on this ballot.
    /// May only be called by $(chairperson).
    function giveRightToVote(address toVoter) public {
        if (msg.sender != chairperson || voters[toVoter].voted) return;
        voters[toVoter].weight = 1;
    }

    /// Delegate your vote to the voter $(to).
    function delegate(address to) public {
        Voter storage sender = voters[msg.sender]; // assigns reference
        if (sender.voted) return;
        while (voters[to].delegate != address(0) && voters[to].delegate != msg.sender)
            to = voters[to].delegate;
        if (to == msg.sender) return;
        sender.voted = true;
        sender.delegate = to;
        Voter storage delegateTo = voters[to];
        if (delegateTo.voted)
            proposals[delegateTo.vote].voteCount += sender.weight;
        else
            delegateTo.weight += sender.weight;
    }

    /// Give a single vote to proposal $(toProposal).
    function vote(uint8 toProposal) public {
        Voter storage sender = voters[msg.sender];
        if (sender.voted || toProposal >= proposals.length) return;
        sender.voted = true;
        sender.vote = toProposal;
        proposals[toProposal].voteCount += sender.weight;
    }

    function winningProposal() public constant returns (uint8 _winningProposal) {
        uint256 winningVoteCount = 0;
        for (uint8 prop = 0; prop < proposals.length; prop++)
            if (proposals[prop].voteCount > winningVoteCount) {
                winningVoteCount = proposals[prop].voteCount;
                _winningProposal = prop;
            }
    }
}
```

Gas Limit: 3000000
Value: 1 Ether

See if you can deploy this to ROPSTEN...

Comment: It is likely a problem with your code that results in a permanently failing tx. Share the contract code, and the transaction parameters.

Comment: I deployed your contract successfully to ropsten without ant change.

Answer (score 0):

Your code is missing the `constructor()` function, see [here](https://solidity.readthedocs.io/en/v0.4.24/contracts.html?highlight=constructor).

Comment: It is using the old syntax `function Ballot()`, but even in that case that should not cause a failure.

Answer (score 0):

your code works fine on my machine.

1) I guess the Remix compilation is having some problem, creating a new solidity file with the same code and re-deploying it might help. 
2) also, try to reload Chrome(Remix tab)
3) otherwise, reinstall Metamask.

hope it helps!